# X freeze with proprietary fglrx driver on radeon HD 5970

Tags: debian, gpu, amd-radeon, debian-squeeze, amd-catalyst

I can't get to install the proprietary driver "fglrx" with ATI Radeon HD 5970 on Debian Squeeze.
After the installation with ATI Catalyst 12-8 and a reboot, from the stage of GDM, the screen is freezing with a lot of little squares appearing on X, mouse is locking and total freezing of the system. I have tried with old Catalyst versions and same problems.

I would like to install the proprietary fglrx driver because I need to use bi-GPU of this card with OpenCL. With the free radeon driver, I have no problem for X but I don't have GPU support.

I also try with "module-assistant" but the issue is the same.

Here's my config :

PC : Aspire G5900-090 - Core i7-870 - 8Go - HD5970 (2048Mo)

```
$ lspci | grep ATI
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Hemlock [ATI Radeon HD 5900 Series]
03:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Cypress HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5800 Series]
04:00.0 Display controller: ATI Technologies Inc Hemlock [ATI Radeon HD 5900 Series]

$ uname -a
Linux sev 3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Jun 3 21:40:57 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

With free radeon driver, "CLInfo" tool of ATI stream SDK makes only appear CPUs :

```
/opt/ati-stream-sdk-v2.1-lnx64/samples/opencl/bin/x86_64 $ ./CLInfo

Number of platforms:             1
  Platform Profile:             FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:             OpenCL 1.0 ATI-Stream-v2.1 (145)
  Platform Name:                ATI Stream
  Platform Vendor:             Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:          cl_khr_icd


  Platform Name:                ATI Stream
Number of devices:             1
  Device Type:                CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Device ID:                4098
  Max compute units:             8
  Max work items dimensions:          3
    Max work items[0]:             1024
    Max work items[1]:             1024
    Max work items[2]:             1024
  Max work group size:             1024
  Preferred vector width char:          16
  Preferred vector width short:          8
  Preferred vector width int:          4
  Preferred vector width long:          2
  Preferred vector width float:          4
  Preferred vector width double:       0
  Max clock frequency:             1200Mhz
  Address bits:                64
  Max memory allocation:          1073741824
  Image support:             No
  Max size of kernel argument:          4096
  Alignment (bits) of base address:       1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                Yes
    Round to nearest even:          Yes
    Round to zero:             No
    Round to +ve and infinity:          No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:       No
  Cache type:                Read/Write
  Cache line size:             0
  Cache size:                0
  Global memory size:             3221225472
  Constant buffer size:             65536
  Max number of constant args:          8
  Local memory type:             Global
  Local memory size:             32768
  Profiling timer resolution:          1
  Device endianess:             Little
  Available:                Yes
  Compiler available:             Yes
  Execution capabilities:           
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:          No
  Queue properties:           
    Out-of-Order:             No
    Profiling :                Yes
  Platform ID:                0x7f6f1e600228
  Name:                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
  Vendor:                GenuineIntel
  Driver version:             1.1
  Profile:                FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                OpenCL 1.0 ATI-Stream-v2.1 (145)
  Extensions:                cl_khr_icd cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_device_fission cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_printf


Passed!
```

Has anyone already got this problem of freezing with the fglrx proprietary driver on Radeon HD 5970 ? Could it be an issue with my screen or with frequencies ?

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: if you could update your question with the results from `fglrxinfo` that would be cool for others looking for the same answer

Answer (score 3):

The `fglrx` drivers are currently in no state to be called anything but beta drivers. The support is abysmal. However, reinstall them using [these](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Proprietary_Drivers_a.k.a._Catalyst.2Ffglrx) methods.

But before you do, make sure you purge the current drivers using:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx`

This is the only course of action, everyone complains about glitchy graphics, unfortunately there is nothing to be done for the support is minimal from AMD's side.